# Model for ice sheet thickness

Tags: thermodynamics, models, ice

How should I proceed to find a formula $\lambda(t)$ for the thickness of and ice sheet in terms of

1. The diference $T_{a}(t)-T_w(t)$ of the temperatures of air above the sheet and water below
2. Thermal conductivity ($k$) and entalphy of fusion ($h$) of ice

Im new to "modelling" this stuff so I haven't made any real progress. All the equations I find online make sense for an ice sheet of area $A$ or take into account the depth of the river/lake or some other factor, but I want to assume that the ice sheet is infinite in extension: an infinite plane with some thickness dividing the space into "water region" and "air region". I wouldn't mind if $T_a$ and $T_w$ are constant (they are regions so huge that their temperatures do not really change).

Please consider explaining some steps that may be obvious in physics. I'm looking for a line of reasoning like "by conservation of energy we should have the following equation _______ which, combined with ______ gives us ______" or something similar. Nothing fancy, only an equation $\lambda(t)=$expression in terms of $k$, $h$ and the temperature difference

Thanks!

Comment: I think you'd also need relative humidity.

Comment: @zonksoft No you don’t

Comment: Are you familiar with Fourier's law of heat conduction?

Comment: I don't know why this thread was closed.  It makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: @ChetMiller No, but I am now. I understand the formula and it makes perfect sense